# Apache Archiva jetty.xml SAXParseException

Tags: apache, archiva

To host repositories I am trying to use Apache-Archiva 2.1.1 . I was able to use the standalone version in my desktop, but I am unable to start the archiva on a mac server.

When I use `./archiva console` shows me this error:

```
jvm 1    | Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/Applications/apache-archiva-2.1.1/conf/jetty.xml; lineNumber: 65; columnNumber: 80; The value of attribute "default" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.
jvm 1    |  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
jvm 1    |  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
jvm 1    |  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
```

Line number 65 is:

```
<Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="8081"/></Set>
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you have a rogue <, >, or " character in your jetty.xml file.

Whatever the case is, Archiva or Jetty's SAX Parser can't parse that .xml file due to an XML typo/error.